# Ember.j - How to update chat when a message is created in database? (firebase as database)

Tags: javascript, firebase, ember.js

I'm new to ember.js and firebase. At the moment I can post messages and see them displayed in a list like this:

```
//templates/show-messages.hbs

{{page-title "ShowMessages"}}

<div class="container">
    <div class="chat-container">
        {{#each this.model as |message|}}
        <div class="bubble">
            <h3>{{message.text}}</h3>
            <p>{{message.username}}</p>
        </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    <ChatInput class="Input" @username="" @text=""></ChatInput>
</div>


//routes/show-messages.js

import Route from '@ember/routing/route';

export default class ShowMessagesRoute extends Route {
  model() {
    return this.store.findAll('chat-message');
  }
}
```

The problem is that when viewing chat in another browser, the chat window doesnt update when I post a message. Hence, the chat doesnt really update like it should.

How do I solve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the official [EmberFire](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/emberfire) add-on? Live reloading as data changes requires subscribing to the source. The add-on [provides](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/emberfire/blob/master/docs/guide/querying-data.md#getting-realtime-updates-to-our-queries) a way to do this easily. Otherwise you'll need to handle this in your application (and I'm not sure how to do that).

Answer (score 0):

In my experience EmberFire is not actively maintained. I would suggest this add-on: [Ember-Cli-Zuglet](https://github.com/ampatspell/ember-cli-zuglet)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).